# Weird windows prompt behavior restoring a dump with psql tool

Tags: windows, postgresql, prompt, dump, psql

I have just installed the postgresql 9.4.2 (64bits) on my windows 7 pro (64 bits) and created a database with the purpose to restore a dump which I generated like this:

```
pg_dump -O -U owner_user my_database > dump_my_database_20141122.sql
```

Now I am trying to restore this dump in this new created database with this command (like I used to do many times before):

```
psql –q –U owner_user my_database < dump_my_database_20141122.sql
```

But windows command prompt seems not to be understanding what the command should do. It is stating this:

```
psql: aviso: argumento extra de linha de comando "owner_user" ignorado
psql: aviso: argumento extra de linha de comando "my_database" ignorado
Senha para usuário -U:
```

That in english should be something like this:

```
psql: Warning: extra command line argument of "owner_user" ignored
psql: Warning: extra command line argument of "my_database" ignored
Password for -U user:
```

I've also tryied many variations of the command changing parameters order passing -f option in the "<" place and so on but nothing seems to work.

Had someone else had this problem? Am I doing something wrong? Is there some change in the psql command in postgresql 9.4.2 version that I'm not knowing about?

I've made a huge search on google but found nothing!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to restore the dump doing this:

```
psql -U owner_user -f dump_my_database_20141122.sql my_database
```

It just worked using the "-f" option and removing the "-q" option. However "-q" option is still listed in the help. Maybe this options isn't valid anymore. Luckily the database is small, otherwise it would flood my console.